# Convert a dictionary including many dataframes into a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe, time-series

I have a dictionary from an influxdb Time-series database. This dictionary includes many keys like KEY1,KEY2... All keys correspond to a tabular dataset. As an example:

```
dict = { KEY1:     MAX      MIN  
         Date1     max1     min1
         Date2     max2     min2,

         KEY2:     MAX      MIN  
         Date1     max3     min3
         Date2     max4     min4}
```

What I want is a data frame like:

```
KEYS     DATES      MAX         MIN
KEY1     Date1      max1        min1
KEY1     Date2      max2        min2
KEY2     Date1      max3        min3
KEY2     Date2      max4        min4
```

I hope it's clear enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a `key` attribute to each dataframe and `concat`, like so:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'k1': pd.DataFrame({'max': [1, 2, 3], 'min': [1, 2, 3]}, index=[0, 1, 2]),
     'k2': pd.DataFrame({'max': [4, 5, 6], 'min': [4, 5, 6]}, index=[3, 4, 5])}

for k in d:
    d[k].insert(0, 'key', [k]*len(d[k]))

res = pd.concat(d.values())
print(res)
```

prints out

```
  key  max  min
0  k1    1    1
1  k1    2    2
2  k1    3    3
3  k2    4    4
4  k2    5    5
5  k2    6    6
```

n.b. this also works if the indices are repeated across dataframes:

```
  key  max  min
0  k1    1    1
1  k1    2    2
2  k1    3    3
0  k2    4    4
1  k2    5    5
2  k2    6    6
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the reduce function from the functools package.  The functools package usually comes with a standard installation of Python.  So, you could write this:

```
from functools import reduce

for key in dict.keys():
    dict[key]["KEYS"] = key

combined = reduce(lambda x,y: x.append(y), dict.values())
```

First, you go through each data frame, and create the "KEYS" column.  Then,
the reduce function will go through the data frames in your dictionary, combining two at a time into one data frame, and then combining that result with the next data frame and so on, until it's gone through all the data frames in the dictionary.

This gets stored in the result variable, combined.

It looks like DATES is the index of each data frame in the dict, so if that's the case, you could add this:

```
combined["DATES"] = combined.index.tolist()
```

You can then rearrange the columns if you want, as well:

```
combined = combined[["KEYS", "DATES", "MAX", "MIN"]]
```

Please let me know if that works for you.

Comment: Hey it gives a ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index.